# Inserting into Multiple Tables within a database from a form

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have searched for a solution to my obstacle at hand for days, but I have not found exactly what I need to continue, I am stuck!

What I am trying to do is register "firstName", "lastName" and "subject" into two tables within the database where one table contains first name and last name. The second table contains only the course.

I have found many posts similar to this topic in stackoverflow but for some reason I couldn't work around those examples.

The view:

```
<form action="/Default/Page" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="firstName" />
   <input type="text" name="lastName" />
   <input type="text" name="subject" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{

public class DefaultController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult page(FormCollection collection)
    {
        App2Context db = new App2Context();
        Model dat = new Model();

        dat.Pupil.First = collection["firstName"];
        dat.Pupil.First = collection["firstName"];
        dat.Study.Subject = collection["Subject"];

        return View("Page2");
    }
  }
}
```

The Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{

public class Model
{
    public Name Pupil { get; set; }
    public Course Study { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

}
```

The DbContext class contains two DbSets which are Names and Courses.

What I have tried so far is to use the object from the context class but the intellisense only shows db.savechanges() It didn't present me with methods to add the object dat into the database. I've tried some LINQ queries but since I'm not very familiar with queries I was just stuck.

The Query:

```
var data = from s in db.Names where dat.Pupil.First equals
```

Then my IDE just have red squiggly lines and doesn't show any more intellisense support.

How can I enter the information I am attempting to collect via the form into the two tables within a database using Entity Framework?

How can I enter the same information into the tables using LINQ queries as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**first argument for where must be from inner**

```
var data = from s in db.Names where s.Name equals dat.Pupil.First
```

otherwise:

```
<form action="/Default/Page" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="firstName" />
   <input type="text" name="lastName" />
   <input type="text" name="subject" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

if your EF looks like:

```
public Class App2Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Model> Models {get;set;}
}
```

but better way's:

```
public Class App2Context : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Name> Names {get;set;}
   public DbSet<Course> Courses {get;set;}
}
```

then in your app:

```
public ActionResult page(FormCollection collection)
{
    App2Context db = new App2Context();
    Model dat = new Model();

    dat.Pupil.First = collection["firstName"];
    dat.Pupil.Last  = collection["lastName"];
    dat.Study.Subject = collection["Subject"];

    db.Models.Add(dat);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("Page2");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries

Comment: it explain that you have other struct in table and other struct you want send to db. Please more details.

Comment: Better way's to create two tables: `Names` and `Course`

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use as follows to insert the data into database using LINQ.

```
db.Models.Add(dat);
db.SaveChanges();
```

After adding model to the db context you must have to use SaveChanges() method.